# Spring Boot With Spring Security with Angular 2+

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, architecture

I am trying to use spring boot with spring security for large scale application and i want to use angular in the front end. 
Unfortunately it seems that all the example are "hacks" and not something that intuitive to use.

We have 2 options we would like to do:

1. One monolithic application that will have client and server under spring boot. In such case spring security will handle the pages and security
2. Create 2 application.. 1 will be Gateway that needs to serve the pages and will pass request to the spring server that will have an API and should be secured with spring security.

[image]

If anyone has another idea you are more than welcome. We really want to use spring security because this is awesome framework.. But it seems that angular 2+ will require to use nodejs also.

Comment: I would suggest you to go with second approach (Micro Service Architecture). Spring Boot Application with security + ZUUL Api Gateway + Angular2 UI App

Comment: It would be great for me. Maybe you have reference as an example? This is what i wanted to do but angular2 app with boot seems like a "hack" according to examples i saw

Comment: *But it seems that angular 2+ will require to use nodejs*: no, it doesn't. I'm not sure where you got that idea from. It's a pure frontend framework, and it sends HTTP requests, without knowing or caring about what handles those http requests on the backend.